# Ionic 5 not able to make an apk

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to make my apk in ionic by running the below command

```
sudo ionic cordova build --release android
```

However i get the error

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/prot-admin/Documents/android-sdk-linux (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build android --release exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this
```

I have the required android sdk and java jdk installed. Also i have gradle 5.6.1 installed.
  I am not able to identfy what i am missing still? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Quick question: do you have Android studio?

If not, just install it. If yes, check if you have these variables in you `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zprofile`

```
# Android on Ionic 
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8) # required java version
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk # required for appbundle (https://medium.com/swlh/generating-an-android-app-bundle-from-your-ionic-app-without-android-studio-5bc3acaf4528)
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin # avdmanager, sdkmanager
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools # adb, logcat
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator # emulator
```

Note that the value of the variables depends on your system/setup (I am using MacOS)

Comment: I was told that I don't need android studio for this